# Border does not change color when mouse over

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, styles

The `Border` does not change background color when mouse over.

```
<Border x:Name="border"
        CornerRadius="3"
        Margin="5"
        Background="PaleGreen">
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="GreenYellow"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set the `Background` in the `Border` it is a local value and takes precedence over the style. Move it into the style by creating a `Setter` and it will work.

- [Dependency property precedence list for reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/dependency-property-value-precedence?view=netdesktop-6.0#dependency-property-precedence-list)

```
<Border x:Name="border"
        CornerRadius="3"
        Margin="5">
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="PaleGreen"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="GreenYellow"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
</Border>
```

Comment: Oh yes, it is sensible. The value was simply overwritten from the beginning. Thank you